# Away3D HoverCamera Pan Angle - relative angle out of 360

Tags: actionscript-3, math, away3d

I'm trying to work out the percentage of rotation of the HoverCamera but .panAngle() returns any number from -infinity to + inifinity, is there a way to work out the current angle out of 360 instead, no matter how times you rotate the camera?

Answer (score 0):

For the mod operator in AS3 you need to check for negative values too:

```
        angle = angle % 360;
        if(angle<0) angle+=360;
```